# How do I correctly configure read_preferance for my Mongo Replicaset SECONDARY node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an express/nodejs app connecting to MongoDB Replicaset and deployed in two data centres.

1. NAM

   - App is deployed in NAM DataCenter under **nam.app.com**
   - mongo0 - PRIMARY; host -> **mongo0.app.com**
2. EU

   - App is deployed in UE DataCenter under **ue.app.com**
   - mongo1 - SECONDARY; host -> **mongo1.app.com**

Here is the code that opens up a connection to replica:

Connection from the EU DC:

```
   const connection =  mongoose.connect(`mongodb://` + process.env.DB_USER + `:` + process.env.DB_PASS + process.env.DB_HOST + `:` + process.env.DB_PORT + `,` + process.env.DB_HOST_READ + `:` + process.env.DB_PORT_READ + `/` + process.env.DB_NAME, {
        readPreference: 'secondary',
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        replicaSet: 'rs0'
    })
```

**As you can see it's also configured with readPreference : secondary with TAGS to specifically read from this or that member and on the query level**

Query from the APP in EU DC:

```
   async read(req, res, next) {

    return await Model.findOne({'_id': req.params.id })
        .read('secondary', { dc:'EU_MONGO1_SECONDARY' })
        .exec()
        .then(response => {
            res.status(200).json(response) })
        .catch(err => { console.log('err :', err) })
}
```

Connection itself is successful, however...

**Expected results:**

- all the Creates/Updates go to Primary (NAM/mongo0.app.com);
- all the read operations from NAM DC go to NAM/ mongo0.app.com;
- all the read operations from EU DC go to EU/mongo1.app.com.

**Actual results:**

- all the Creates/Updates go to Primary (NAM/mongo0.app.com);
- 90% of the read operations from NAM go to NAM/mongo0.app.com, however 10% go to EU/mongo1.app.com.
- 90% of the read operations from EU DC go to NAM/mongo0.app.com, and only 10% goes to EU DC mongo1.app.com which is the SECONDARY and has the read preference configured.

Mongo monitor shows clearly query/read traffic distribution (as per above actual results) between primary and secondary, **thus the readPreference is completely ignored. I do not understand why it's even defaulting to this weird distribution between two hosts**

Could you please advise what is wrong/ missing with the setup?

I am using:

- mongoose: "^5.3.7"
- Mongodb: 4.0.5
- node: 8.9.1